# Filter JavaScript object according to one attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

My json file is like this.

```
[
  {
    "ArtistID": 1,
    "FollowerID": 1,
    "Name": "JAYAH-Paradiso",
    "Location": "UK",
    "Latitude": "51.5",
    "Longitude": "0.1167",
    "Date": "22/03/2014"
  },
  {
    "ArtistID": 1,
    "FollowerID": 2,
    "Name": "Yasmin Dan",
    "Location": "London",
    "Latitude": "51.5072",
    "Longitude": "0.1275",
    "Date": "22/03/2014"
  },
  {
    "ArtistID": 2,
    "FollowerID": 1,
    "Name": "Daniel Sutka",
    "Location": "London",
    "Latitude": "51.5072",
    "Longitude": "0.1275",
    "Date": "22/03/2014"
  },
  {
    "ArtistID": 2,
    "FollowerID": 2,
    "Name": "Colton Brown",
    "Location": "Moore Haven, Florida",
    "Latitude": "26.8333",
    "Longitude": "81.1",
    "Date": "22/03/2014"
  }
]
```

I want to display the Followers of Artist 1 and Artist 2 in a map. And i want to display those data separately like Location of Followers of Artist 1 in RED circles and Location of Followers of Artist 2 in Blue circles.

And there are 2 buttons for Artist 1 and Artist 2. When i click on Artist 1 button it should display only red color circles.

Can somebody tell me a way to group these data using the ArtistID so that i can use it in those button clicks?

**OR**

I have those sets of circles on a map like 10 red circles(Artist1), 10 blue circles(Artist2), 10 green circles(Artist3). How can i select only red circles using d3 selectAll or select?

Or is there any other methods than that?

the color has been given like this(as the value of "fill" in "style" attribute,

```
feature = g.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.ArtistID + d.FollowerID; })
                    .style("stroke", "black")
                    .style("opacity", .6)
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        if (d.ArtistID == 1) { return "red" }
                        else if (d.ArtistID == 2) { return "blue" }
                        else { return "green" }
                        ;
                    })
                    .attr("r", 10);
```

so, the circles will be drawn like this,

```
<circle id="10" r="10" transform="translate(695,236)" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.6; fill: rgb(255, 255, 0);"></circle>
```

I want to select the circles of red color.

**Either filtering data of the json file, or selecting only circles of one color would help.**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you looked at filter? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter. Just check the element for the `ArtistID` and do/call whatever is different.

Comment: it's not working with other d3 methods :/

Comment: Check out [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642422/array-manipulation-with-d3-nest-and-rollup/25651121#25651121).

Comment: @Isu you should put some code up then for others to be able to help you better. `filter` allows for you to separate the data like you asked for. Something like `var followersOfA1 = data.filter(isArtist1); var followersOfA2 = data.filter(isArtist2);` separates into two arrays of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to filter the data and get the Array of the followers of the Artist 2:

```
<html>
 <head>     
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
 <script>
$(function() {
        var json =  '[{"ArtistID":1,"FollowerID":1,"Name":"JAYAH-Paradiso","Location":"UK","Latitude":"51.5","Longitude":"0.1167","Date":"22/03/2014"},{"ArtistID":1,"FollowerID":2,"Name":"Yasmin Dan","Location":"London","Latitude":"51.5072","Longitude":"0.1275","Date":"22/03/2014"},{"ArtistID":1,"FollowerID":3,"Name":"Aaron Senior","Location":"London,UK","Latitude":"51.5072","Longitude":"0.1275","Date":"22/03/2014"},{"ArtistID":2,"FollowerID":1,"Name":"Daniel Sutka","Location":"London","Latitude":"51.5072","Longitude":"0.1275","Date":"22/03/2014"},{"ArtistID":2,"FollowerID":2,"Name":"Colton Brown","Location":"Moore Haven, Florida","Latitude":"26.8333","Longitude":"81.1","Date":"22/03/2014"},{"ArtistID":2,"FollowerID":3,"Name":"Thia Kirby","Location":"England","Latitude":"51.5","Longitude":"0.1167","Date":"22/03/2014"}]';

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

        console.log(obj);

        var newArray = obj.filter( function (el) { return el.ArtistID == 2 } );

        console.log(newArray);
});
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it gives an error in the browser console saying "json is not defined" o.O

Answer (score 1):

try to get required field using this:

```
<script>
var json = [
 {
   "ArtistID": 1,
   "FollowerID": 1,
   "Name": "JAYAH-Paradiso",
   "Location": "UK",
   "Latitude": "51.5",
   "Longitude": "0.1167",
   "Date": "22/03/2014"
 },
 {
   "ArtistID": 1,
   "FollowerID": 2,
   "Name": "Yasmin Dan",
   "Location": "London",
   "Latitude": "51.5072",
   "Longitude": "0.1275",
   "Date": "22/03/2014"
 },
 {
   "ArtistID": 2,
   "FollowerID": 1,
   "Name": "Daniel Sutka",
   "Location": "London",
   "Latitude": "51.5072",
   "Longitude": "0.1275",
   "Date": "22/03/2014"
 },
 {
   "ArtistID": 2,
   "FollowerID": 2,
   "Name": "Colton Brown",
   "Location": "Moore Haven, Florida",
   "Latitude": "26.8333",
   "Longitude": "81.1",
   "Date": "22/03/2014"
 }
];
var data = eval(json);
for(x in data){
    alert(data[x].ArtistID);
if(){//check condition on ArtistID and use the data
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using underscore for this. (Especially if you are doing more operations like this.) The where function describes what you are looking for.

`_.where(array, {ArtistID: X});`

http://underscorejs.org

edit: the groupBy method may also be of use to you in this situation.